# How Memcached negotiate the protocol?

Tags: memcached, binary, protocols, ascii

I know that Memcached can negotiate protocol with the client, but I know nothing (neither can found anything on Internet) about the negotiation mechanism the server use. Any idea?

Comment: I really think that this is a question for serverfault instead of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/master/memcached.c#L3648), it is all based on the first byte received by the server. If it is a magic request byte (0x80), then it considers that the client tries to use the binary protocol, otherwise it will use the ascii protocol.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can I test that using netcat?

Comment: For ASCII, I guess it is fairly easy, just use "echo -e 'stats conns\r\n' | nc localhost 11211". For binary, you could do the same but use something like "echo -e '\x80....' | nc ...", just read the binary proto desc.

Comment: This worked: **echo -e '\x80' | nc host port** Thanks a lot, was fun ;)

Answer (score 0):

At function try_read_command ：

```
if ((unsigned char)c->rbuf[0] == (unsigned char)**PROTOCOL_BINARY_REQ**) {
        c->protocol = binary_prot;
    } else {
        c->protocol = ascii_prot;
}
```

```
typedef enum {
    PROTOCOL_BINARY_REQ = 0x80,
    PROTOCOL_BINARY_RES = 0x81
} protocol_binary_magic;
```